# Why is this algorithm linear and not linearithmic?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

```
int sum = 0; 
for (int n = N; n > 0; n /= 2)
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      sum++;
```

I was pretty sure it grows in nlogn but was told it's linear... Why is it linear and not linearithmic?

Comment: "linearithmic"?  Do you mean "logarithmic"?

Comment: @duffymo: [linearithmic](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/linearithmic)

Comment: Never heard that term before.  I might call it log-linear.  I'll Google your term.

Comment: log linear already has a different meaning.

Comment: First time I've heard it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is linear. Imagine for a second `n` is 64. The inner loop runs 64 times, then 32 times, then 16 times, then 8 times, then 4 times, then 2 times, then 1 time. 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 127.

So it requires `2n-1` total operations (for a power of 2, but that doesn't change the analysis), assuming the inner loop is not optimized away. That's clearly `O(n)` -- linear.

If the inner for loop is optimized away (to `sum += n;`), it's logarithmic.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, isn't it hitting every element once on the inner loop the first time?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Nice catch, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 10):

The complexity of this algorithm is Θ(N).

The number of operations is

```
sum{2**k} for k = 0..log2(N)
```

The sum of this progression is

```
2*N-1
```

which is Θ(N).

Comment: probably `k = 0..log2(N)` - not that it makes a difference to the conclusion

Comment: hmm I see. I am not quite familiar with that notation. "0..log2(N)"

Answer (score 2):

Formally, using Sigma Notation can help you to see clearly that the order of growth is linear.

[image]